# Different results passing system.string as either function parameter or constant

Tags: string, delphi, delphi-xe7, lockbox

I've been fighting for hours on a very strange phenomenon. First of all, I'm using the [TurboPower LockBox v10](http://sourceforge.net/projects/turbopowerlockboxnew/) encryption library (using `TLbRijndael`), but I'm not convinced that's what's at fault. I need to pass a key into the encrypt/decrypt functions, so naturally I created functions like this:

```
function EncryptText(const S: String; const Key: String): String;
function DecryptText(const S: String; const Key: String): String;
```

Oddly, while the encryption *seems* to work, when I try to decrypt, it returns complete garbage. So, on my hours-long journey digging to find the reason, what I found absolutely baffles me. When I use an encryption key defined as a constant, everything works. But passing the exact same value (also `system.string`) as a parameter in the function, it does not.

So to summarize that:

- When passing key as constant (`system.string`), everything works fine.
- When passing key as parameter (`system.string`), results are random and incorrect (and fails to decrypt).

Here's a demo I put together to show what's happening (my third test application trying to figure this out):

```
program EncDecDemo;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.Classes, System.SysUtils,
  LbCipher, LbClass, LbAsym, LbRSA;

const
  ENC_KEY = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstubwxyz123456';

var
  EncComp: TLbRijndael;

function EncAsConst(const S: String): String;
begin
  EncComp.SetKey(ENC_KEY); //<-- works as expected
  Result:= EncComp.EncryptString(S);
end;

function DecAsConst(const S: String): String;
begin
  EncComp.SetKey(ENC_KEY); //<-- works as expected
  Result:= EncComp.DecryptString(S);
end;

function EncAsParam(const S: String; const Key: String): String;
begin
  EncComp.SetKey(Key); //<-- produces random results
  Result:= EncComp.EncryptString(S);
end;

function DecAsParam(const S: String; const Key: String): String;
begin
  EncComp.SetKey(Key); //<-- produces random results
  Result:= EncComp.DecryptString(S);
end;

var
  InputStr: String;
  EncrStr: String;
  DecrStr: String;
  Ctr: Integer;

begin
  EncComp:= TLbRijndael.Create(nil);
  try
    EncComp.Encoding:= TEncoding.UTF8;
    EncComp.KeySize:= ks256;
    WriteLn('Enter a string to encrypt: ');
    ReadLn(Input, InputStr);
    WriteLn;
    WriteLn('Encrypting as constants...');
    EncrStr:= EncAsConst(InputStr);
    DecrStr:= DecAsConst(EncrStr);
    WriteLn('Pass 1:   Enc = '+EncrStr+'   Dec = '+DecrStr);
    EncrStr:= EncAsConst(InputStr);
    DecrStr:= DecAsConst(EncrStr);
    WriteLn('Pass 2:   Enc = '+EncrStr+'   Dec = '+DecrStr);
    EncrStr:= EncAsConst(InputStr);
    DecrStr:= DecAsConst(EncrStr);
    WriteLn('Pass 3:   Enc = '+EncrStr+'   Dec = '+DecrStr);
    WriteLn;
    WriteLn('Encrypting as parameters...');
    EncrStr:= EncAsParam(InputStr, ENC_KEY);
    WriteLn('Pass 1:   Enc = '+EncrStr);
    EncrStr:= EncAsParam(InputStr, ENC_KEY);
    WriteLn('Pass 2:   Enc = '+EncrStr);
    EncrStr:= EncAsParam(InputStr, ENC_KEY);
    WriteLn('Pass 3:   Enc = '+EncrStr);
    EncrStr:= EncAsParam(InputStr, ENC_KEY);
    WriteLn('Pass 4:   Enc = '+EncrStr);
    EncrStr:= EncAsParam(InputStr, ENC_KEY);
    WriteLn('Pass 5:   Enc = '+EncrStr);
    EncrStr:= EncAsParam(InputStr, ENC_KEY);
    WriteLn('Pass 6:   Enc = '+EncrStr);
    WriteLn;
    WriteLn('Press enter to exit');
    ReadLn;
  finally
    EncComp.Free;
  end;
end.
```

[image]

As you can see, when passing the exact same value as a parameter in the function, it produces a different result each time. Let me reiterate that, *the exact same value*.

My only conclusion is that `system.string` when used as a constant (`const ENC_KEY = 'value';`) is somehow a different size or type behind the scenes than when used as a variable.

When I look inside the `SetKey` procedure, it's a simple `Move` call...

```
procedure TLbRijndael.SetKey(const Key);
begin
  Move(Key, FKey, FKeySizeBytes);
end;
```

(where `FKey` is `array [0..31] of Byte;`)

What's going wrong here and how to resolve it?

Comment: This almost looks like a Unicode issue at first, but then I reach the end and see that SetKey takes an untyped parameter, not an `AnsiString`...

Comment: It would be great if downvoters were forced to write a comment explaining their reason.

Comment: @Jerry: (I didn't downvote.) Voting here is anonymous, and requiring a comment for a reason would break that policy. This has also been discussed at length in [meta].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
procedure TLbRijndael.SetKey(const Key);
begin
  Move(Key, FKey, FKeySizeBytes);
end;
```

What you pass to this untyped parameter is the problem. When you pass a true constant, the text is passed. When you pass a string variable, the address of the text is passed, rather than the text itself. That's because a string variable is actually a pointer to the text.

I believe you will need to stop using a string variable as the key and provide an binary buffer.

Consider this program that illustrates the issue:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

procedure Foo(const Key);
var
  buff: Pointer;
begin
  Move(Key, buff, SizeOf(buff));
  Writeln(Format('%p', [buff]));
end;

const
  ENC_KEY = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstubwxyz123456';

var
  str: string = ENC_KEY;

begin
  Foo(ENC_KEY);
  Foo(str);
  Writeln(Format('%p', [Pointer(str)]));
end.
```

On my machine the output is:

```
00620061
00419D48
00419D48
```

The first line is the text `'ab'` encoded as UTF-16LE. The second line is the address of `str`, as confirmed by the third line.

I'd like to stress the importance of the distinction between text and binary.

Comment: Thanks. As for your last comment about binary, first of all this is a demo, second of all this library supports many types, and I'm specifically using the string part (which automagically converts it to binary) :-)

Comment: I really do urge you to stop thinking of encryption as something that operates on text. It operates on binary, using binary keys. By all means use Unicode encodings like UTF-8, and encodings like base64. But keep that front and centre and don't let it be hidden as currently seems to be the case.

Comment: That's very understood. I'm not thinking of it as text, not sure why you think I am. But for my above demo, to be more user-friendly, I did a text example. As I said, the library I'm using does support binary, along with string wrapped around that. Also, for the purpose of why I'm using encryption, it will only be used as text anyway, so that's the level I'm operating at. Do you want me to ignore the library's built-in conversion and convert it myself?

Comment: I don't think you understand my points at all. If you want me to elaborate I will. But not until tomorrow.

Comment: Did you intend for your key to be UTF-16 encoded? Do you know every other byte of the key is zero? Personally I would never use the convenience functions that operate on strings. Binary all the way. Convert from text to binary with UTF-8. To present binary in text form use base64.

Comment: I see, I figured you were talking about the actual data being encrypted decrypted, but now I realize you're talking about the key. Apologies.

Comment: Resolved by converting the key to the library's `TKey256` type and passing that instead.

Comment: @Jerry - It's also possible to pass character data of a string, like SetKey(Key[1]).

Comment: I'm talking about the data too